# A group of monkeys are given two tasks to do. Probability

Tags: probability

Can you help me in this question? I would like to know if I am doing it right. A group of monkeys are given two tasks to do, the second of which is harder than the first. A proportion $(3/5)$ get the first one right and $(7/15)$ get the second one right. If a monkey gets the first one right, it has a conditional probability of $(5/8)$ of also performing the second task right. One monkey is chosen at random from the group.

Let $A$ be the event the 1st task is right and let $B$ be the event the 2nd task is right. So $$P(A)=3/5,\,\, P(B)=7/15,\,\, P(A')=2/5,\,\, P(B')=8/15,\,\, P(B\mid A)=5/8$$

1. What is the probability that it gets both tasks right? I did: $$P(A\cap B)=P(B\mid A)\cdot P(A)=(5/8)\cdot(3/5)=3/8$$ right?
2. What is the probability that it gets at least one right? I did: $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=(3/5)+(7/15)-(3/8)=83/120$$ right?
3. If the monkey got the first task wrong, what is the conditional probability that it will also get the second one wrong? I did: 
   $$P(B'\mid A')= \frac{P(A'\cap B')}{P(A')}=37/48$$ right?
4. If the monkey got the second task wrong, what is the probability that its first task was correctly carried out? I did: 
   $$P(A\mid B')=\frac{P(A\cap B')}{P(B')}=\frac{P(A)-P(A\cap B)}{1-P(B)}=27/64$$

Can you please let me know if I am thinking in the right way?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, everything you have is perfectly correct.

Comment: 1 is correct. 2 is correct. 3. I'm not sure that there's any information in the question which relates between these events, hence the answer is simply $1-\frac{7}{15}$ (but again, I'm not sure). 4. I think the answer is simply $1-\frac58$.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with 1. and 2.

The way you start 3. is valid, but $P(A' \cap B')$ has to be computed first (it's not given), say as $P(B' | A')P(A') = (1 - p(B|A'))P(A')$. Ok, $P(A') = 1 - P(A) = \frac{2}{5}$.

But what is $P(B | A')$? Well, we know that

$$P(B) = P(B | A)P(A) + P(B|A')P(A')$$

by conditioning on $A$, and all of the probabilities are known except $P(B|A')$. So you can compute it, and then $P(A' \cap B')$ and then $P(B' | A')$

Or we could directly compute it:

$$P(B') = P(B' | A)P(A) + P(B'|A')P(A') = (1-P(B|A))P(A) + P(B'|A')P(A')$$ where again all is known except $P(B'|A')$.

I see no problem with 4.